# Excel: how do I insert changing cell values in my sum?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to find the sum of `A3` lots of `A1` multiplied by `A2`, where the value of `A2` changes depending on the value of `A3`.

For example, if `A3` is 3, then I would like to find `((A1*A2(where A1 is 1))+(A1*A2(where A1 is 2))+(A1*A2(where A1 is 3)))`. Is there a way to do this in Excel? Thanks

Comment: What formula or function is changing these values? If you've already tried a few methods, please post a screenshot of what you've got so far.

Comment: A3 is just a number between 1 and 30. A1 is always 0.8. The formula for A2 is =B1*(1+B35)^A3

Comment: Please post a screenshot or a sample file and mock up a few scenarios. Your explanation is hard to grasp. What does `where A1 is x` mean, especially since you say that A1 is always 0.8?

Comment: Thanks. All I am trying to do is calculate the property tax I will pay on my house over n years. The property tax will be the sum of the tax I pay in each year. But the tax in each year will depend on the value of the house, which also depends on n. So, I have A1 as n years; A2 is the property tax (.81%); and A3 is the value of the house in the nth year (which depends on n, that is, the value in A1).

Comment: It really sounds like you're creating a *financial model* in excel. There are a lot of [financial functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/financial-functions-reference-HP010342519.aspx) available, but modeling is pretty complex for baseline users. Take a look at some of those functions to see if they might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a circular reference.  This type of formula changes its value based on a formula that somewhere asks for its value.

In this case `A3 = A1 * A2` and `A2 = Formula with A3`

I'm sure you got a circular reference warning when completing the second formula.

In Excel click File --> Options  Click on Enable Iterative calculation and set it's values.

[image: Excel options]