# Nested If Statements Without Invoking Circular Reference Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that calculates perfectly, except in one case near the end where it becomes negative.  I was wondering if it would be possible to have the cell containing the formula say "If this formula results in a negative value then do something else."  I know how to do this with a helper column but I was wondering if any Excel gurus know of a way to do this all within the same cell. To my knowledge there isn't a way to do it without invoking a circular reference error.

Comment: Perhaps you can add an example of what you mean? Like the data you have and what you want it to do?

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://superuser.com/questions/747260/excel-how-do-i-insert-changing-cell-values-in-my-sum/747352#747352 or are you talking about a [worksheet change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Comment: @Raystafarian I think I'm talking about a change event, thanks Ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't overcome a circular reference with a formula, you'll need VBA at the worksheet level using a [worksheet_change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).

---

<s>Sure, just use an `if`. Something like -</s>

```
=if(sum(A1:A5)<0,somethingelse,sum(A1:A5)
```

This will do the formula (`sum` in this example) as long as `sum` > 0, otherwise it will do "somethingelse'

Or reverse it

```
=if(sum(A1:A5)>=0,sum(A1:A5),""
```

Comment: Right, but this requires a helper cell doesn't it?  You couldn't use this formula in A1:A5.

Comment: @114 No, but how would you have the initial formula in the cells (A1:A5) in the first place? Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think what I'm asking for is impossible - I'm essentially looking for a way around the circular reference.

Comment: @114 why? what are you trying to accomplish? This is only possible with VBA.

Comment: For some cell the value resulting from the formula calculation will be negative - when this event occurs I'd like Excel to use another formula.  I think you're right about this requiring VBA.

Comment: @114 in the "for some cell the value resulting from the formula" can't include its own address, so there's no way to check if it's negative. In other words, the scenario you present isn't possible in the first place.

Comment: Yes, so it would require dynamic calculations from VBA, right?

Comment: I don't see how VBA would help, as there are no iterations in a spread-sheet. In an iterative language like C you can write `if (a1+a2+a3+a4+a5>=0) a3=a1+a2+a3+a4+a5'; else ...`, making a new value partly dependent on its previous value. A spread-sheet has no previous values, and a value cannot depend on itself. The best you can do is to make A3 dependent on the _other_ values in the column: `=IF(SUM(A1:A2)+SUM(A4:A5)>=0,SUM(A1:A2)+SUM(A4:A5),...)`. Using a separate cell won't help - it will simply change self-recursion to mutual recursion. Unfortunately you can't use `SUM(A1:A5)-A3)`.

Comment: @AFH OP isn't using `sum`. In fact, I'm still not clear what the question is about. But a `worksheet_selectionchange` event can help store previous values and utilize `worksheet_change` to call the stored value. With those you could theoretically do a running sum in a single cell, I don't know why you would, but you could.

Comment: @Raystafarian - Thanks. I was unaware of this facility. As far as I knew, a spread-sheet uses a lot of defined values and a lot of calculated values, and when any of the defined values changes, the calculations immediately reflect the change. I didn't know you had access to values prior to a change. I find great difficulty in seeing how such calculations might be interpreted, especially after a number of values change in succession. Like you, "I don't know why you would".